# AppArmor profile enforced for different users

Tags: security, system, apparmor

Is there a native way to enforce AppArmor profiles on a user basis.

Enforcing two profiles for one program for different user groups.

- For user 1 example.sh permits xyz and denies abc.
- For user 2 example.sh permits abc and denies xyz.

As from what I read, this doesn't appear possible.

I suppose I could imitate this behavior by copying the binaries and placing them somewhere else on the file system and changing the path for each user. I want to know if this there's a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with pam_apparmor.

Unfortunately this is essentially a boiler plate using PAM as a way to divy out permissions using owner conditional rules.

https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/wikis/pam_apparmor.